# Load a different div onclick jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple lightbox for a static site using jquery.

When I click a link the lightbox appears and you can close it again by clicking a cross.

I have several divs which I want to load into the lightbox, I obviously only want one to appear at a time. As I have it just now, if you click any link they all appear at the same time.
This is because the all have a class `.hidden`, which styles them. I can't figure out how to load one div inside the lightbox depending on which link is clicked.

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C5XmJ/) to give you a better understanding.

I could obviously do them all individually writing functions for every individual div.

There's over 30 divs so I just wondered if there's a simple way around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the index function to determine which link has been clicked:

```
var index = $(".hidden-click").index(this);
$(".trans, .hidden:eq(" + index + ")").fadeIn(500);
```

Full code:

```
$(".hidden-click").click(function() {

    var index = $(".hidden-click").index(this);

    $(".trans, .hidden:eq(" + index + ")").fadeIn(500);
});

$(".cross-link").click(function() { 

     $(".trans, .hidden").fadeOut(500);
});
```

[and a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C5XmJ/1/)

Comment: Thank you, if you have a minute can you explain what the first function is doing?

Comment: sure! you are selecting $(".hidden-click") elements, which generates an array of elements. you call the index function on that array, comparing each array element against being this = the clicked element. as soon as it finds this in the selected elements, it returns the index, id est the key/ position within the array (0-based) :) got that? i can write a function as example

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data` attribute like this -

```
<div class="trans" style="display:none">
    <div class="cross-link">X</div>
</div>

<div class="hidden hidden-one" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="hidden hidden-two" style="display:none"></div>

<div class="one hidden-click" data-id='one'>ONE</div>
<div class="two hidden-click" data-id='two'>TWO</div>
```

Script :

```
$(".hidden-click").click(function() { 
     var id = $(this).data('id');
     $(".trans, .hidden.hidden-"+id).fadeIn(500);
});

$(".cross-link").click(function() { 
     $(".trans, .hidden").fadeOut(500);
});
```

Demo `----->`  http://jsfiddle.net/C5XmJ/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".hidden-click").click(function() { 
 var index=$(this).index();
 $(".trans").fadeIn(500);
$('.hidden').eq(index).fadeIn(500);
});

$(".cross-link").click(function() { 
    $(".trans, .hidden").fadeOut(500);
});


    http://jsfiddle.net/C5XmJ/3/  updated the fiddle
```